# Run react-native IOS with error : Unexpected token

Tags: ios, react-native

Try to run react native project on IOS emulator with the error below,

```
error: bundling failed: SyntaxError: /Users/davidbong/Documents/Wallet/golden-wallet-react-native/node_modules/react-native-view-shot/src/index.js: Unexpected token (180:39)
```

[image: Error Message]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please change following code snippet in that fixes compile error in metro pacakge

> react-native-view-shot/src/index.js file

```
resolveFirstLayout: (layout: Object) => void;
  firstLayoutPromise = new Promise(resolve => {
    this.resolveFirstLayout = resolve;
  });
```

It will resolve error completely.

Comment: Thank you so much and you saved my day! Why does that happen? Could it be due to versioning?

Comment: Just wondering the code above does it causing any uncertainties?

Comment: I think react-native-view-shot should be released with this fix and you can find this change in react-native-view-shot index.js master branch.